# How to execute a php file from Android

Tags: php, android

I tried calling a php file from android using httpurlconnection but it didnt work,can someone help me with this.

Comment: Please take some time with your question. Be more specific with what you need help with. Tell us what you have tried so far. Show us some of your code.

Comment: Look at questions in the Andriod tagged area and you will see 100's of examples

Answer (score -1):

As long as the PHP-script is reachable via a URL, and the webserver is set to execute PHP-scripts, your call will work as long as the device has an active Internet connection.

Maybe you're calling the script, but:

1. The script is not outputting anything
2. Your application isn't set to receive or store any output?

Provide us with some code and we can provide some more help.
Without any code, we can only speculate as to what is the issue.

Comment: This is not suited as an answer. You should use the comment function.

Comment: I would think it is. I suggested him some possible fixes, and things he should check for.

Comment: That is not an answer to the question. It is suggestions.

Comment: Technically, it's not a question.

Comment: Technically its not a question answered by what is not an answer.